# Erro ao enviar dado do Ajax para script em PHP

Tags: jquery, ajax

Tô tentando pegar um email por um input, transmitir pro servidor através do Ajax, e do lado do servidor tem um script que usa a classe PHPMailer, pra enviar um email, e o código PHP sem receber variável funciona, então o erro provavelmente tá no Ajax

HTML

```
form id="emailForm">
        <label for="campoEmail" class="has-information" hidden="false">Email enviado com sucesso</label>
        <input id="campoEmail" class="input-center" placeholder="Digite aqui" type="email" name="email" required="true">
        </br>
        </br>
        <input id="enviar" type="submit">
      </form>
```

Javascript com Jquery

```
$('#emailForm').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/email.php',
        data: 'email=' + $('#campoEmail').val(),
        success:alert("Sucesso")
    });
});
```

});

O PHP foi testado separado e tá funcionando

Comment: E qual é o erro? O email não é enviado ou o alerta não é exibido?

Comment: O código PHP não é acionado, através do AJAX, a sua resposta consertou o o parametro "sucess", agr ele não aparece mais

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui aqui no PHP [Código](https://gist.github.com/lucas2213690/0b8a7e3b3bf1712f0165cabb9409194c)

Comment: Cara, se o código php não é acionado, é a sua URL que tá errada. Ou, se por acaso ele está sendo acionado e não executa nada, provavelmente você tem que verificar se a variável `email` está com algum valor. Faça esses testes no PHP e veja onde especificamente o erro acontece.

Comment: Tipo, tão na mesma pasta no servidor, mas se eu abrir o 'email.php' separado, ele executa tranquilo, mas quando eu chamo através do AJAX não executa

Comment: Se ambos estão na mesma pasta, não há por que usar caminho absoluto. Pode ser aí o erro, editei minha resposta. Pra ver o que está ocorrendo, utilize a aba Network das Ferramentas do Desenvolvedor do seu navegador.

Comment: Era o diretório do arquivo.php, já resolvi, quando coloca **/email.php**, ele busca no diretorio root

Answer (score 3):

Na função `$.ajax([settings])` o parâmetro `settings` aceita essa chave `success`, mas o valor dela deve ser uma função, [conforme a documentação](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings). Você especificou uma chamada a uma função, que não retorna uma função – alert() retorna `undefined`.
O trecho `success:alert("Sucesso")` deve ser: `success: function() { alert("Sucesso"); }`

Outro problema, você disse que eles estão na mesma pasta no servidor, e no entanto especificou um caminho absoluto ao email.php. Isso funciona se ambos estiverem na raiz, mas como você não disse isso e tá dando erro, experimente trocar `url: '/email.php',` por `url: 'email.php',`.